# Create file using sudo

Tags: file, go

I am looking to create a file using Go's os.Create(filename) method (equivalent to 'mkdir filename'). However I do not have write permissions in the folder. Is there a Go method for 'sudo mkdir filename'? I have not been able to find any reference to this in the official docs or other places.

Comment: "Is there a golang method for 'sudo mkdir filename'?" Plain no. Like in every other language. That's simply not how sudo works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The golang executable is executed from the user's context who runs the executable. If you do `go run main.go`, it runs as "you". If you do `sudo go run main.go` it will run as root.

For this reason, just write your application as if it has sudo. And make sure you run `sudo go run main.go`.

An example program that writes to a file: https://goplay.tools/snippet/_N96gaDGAvD

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // Choose your own perms here
    file, err := os.OpenFile("myfile.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = file.WriteString("Hello World!")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    file.Close()

    data, err := os.ReadFile("myfile.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a build in `sudo` in go. However, there are some external libraries that allow executing shell commands from Go code, such as `os/exec` and `syscall`.

An other option could be to first change the permission with `os.chmod` to allow yourself write access, create the file, and then change the permissions back to their original state.

Or to create a user with exact the required permissions and run the program with this user.

Comment: wont chmod also require sudo access?